# Use the AGM inequality to find the maximum

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Use the AGM inequality to find the maximum of $(5+\sqrt{x^4+1}) \cdot (9-\sqrt{x^4 + 1})$.

$$ab \le (\frac{a+b}{2})^2$$

I don't know how to relate this inequality to find the maximum of that.

Comment: take $a=5+\sqrt{x^4+1}$ and $b=9-\sqrt{x^4+1}$, answer would be $49$, I guess.

Comment: Have you tried using the inequality with $a = 5 +\sqrt{x^4+1}$ and $b = 9-\sqrt{x^4+1}$?

Comment: I don't think that this will tell you what the maximum is but it will give you an upper bound on said maximum.

Comment: @Tucker but how can one be sure that any of a or b is not less than $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $a=5+\sqrt{x^4+1}, b=9-\sqrt{x^4+1}$. Then:
$$ab\le 49$$
Equality occurs when $x=\pm\sqrt[4]{3}$.

Because:
$$ab=(5+\sqrt{x^4+1})(9-\sqrt{x^4+1})\le \left(\frac{(5+\sqrt{x^4+1})+(9-\sqrt{x^4+1})}{2}\right)^2=7^2=49.$$

Comment: How did you get $ab \le 49$?

Comment: Please, see the details.

Comment: I guess you also have to add if $b$ is negative you can not attain maximum(also a good argument for that, I guess)

Comment: @MANMAID, it is not necessary, because equality guarantees maximum value and if $b<0$, then $ab<0\le \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$.

Comment: I think $ab \le (\frac{a+b}{2})^2$ come form $\sqrt{ab} \le (\frac{a+b}{2})$. So $ab$ can not be negative.

Comment: @MANMAID, be careful, they are not equivalent, because for $\sqrt{ab}\le \frac{a+b}{2}$, it is required $a,b\ge 0$. However, $ab\le \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$ is true for all real $a,b$, because it is equivalent with $(a-b)^2\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Let $a= 5 + \sqrt{x^4+1}$ and $b = 9 - \sqrt{x^4+1}$.

To show that indeed the maximum value can be attain, recall that equality for $AM-GM$ inequality holds when $a=b$. Show that $a=b$ has a solution.

Comment: Which one is the AM and GM in this question?

Comment: $\sqrt{ab}$ is the geometry mean, $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is the airthmetic mean.